# System hangs after IncreaseUserVa change on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, memory, bcdedit

By mistake, I applied the IncreaseUserVa 3072 on a Windows 7 64-bit:

```
BCDEDIT /set IncreaseUserva 3072
```

After that, the system is getting hanged when I start an intensive Matlab code.

I tried to revert the change using both:

```
BCDEDIT /set increaseUserva 2048
```

or

```
BCDEDIT /deletevalue increaseUserva
```

But, I get to the same problem when I run the Matlab code.

When I check `bcdedit/enum all`, it does not contain `increaseUserva`, after `/deletevalue` command.

Any idea?

Comment: You were right `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVA 2048` (should) fix your problem. Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: Thanks. It seems `BCDEDIT /deletevalue increaseUserva` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`BCDEDIT` was working fine. The correct command is: `BCDEDIT /deletevalue increaseUserva`. The problem was with another change that I made at the same time; in the Matlab code, I added a `try/catch` around the command that was requiring a large amount of memory. Apparently, this was leading Matlab to commit a large amount of memory (40 GB in Resource Monitor was observed). Now, I replaced `try/catch` with an `if` and it works.